# Get null, empty or undefined for file type extensions if there is no extension of file exists on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have got scenario in which the files may not have extensions for some of it as for example:

`http://www.example.com/uploads/abc`

When I am using split and pop as `.split('.').pop()`, it is working fine for `http://www.example.com/uploads/def.png`, `http://www.example.com/uploads/xyz.pdf` and returning the correct extensions of the files But for `http://www.example.com/uploads/abc`, I am getting `com/uploads/abc` which is not intendent. I have tried `slice`, `regular expressions` as well but not working as designed.

Is it possible to have `NULL`, EMPTY STRING or `UNDEFINED` for such scenario in the variable for file extensions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple solution. You split your string up by `/`, reverse it and select the first element. This will always be `abc` or `abc.pdf`. Now you need to split it up again with `.` and select again the first element and its done

```js
let string = "http://www.example.com/uploads/abc";
let string2 = "http://www.example.com/uploads/abc.pdf";
let string3 = "http://www.example.com/uploads/abc.pdf.dot.more.dots";

function getExt(str){
   let last = str.split("/").reverse()[0]
   return last.includes(".") ? last.split(".").reverse()[0] : undefined; 
}

console.log(getExt(string));
console.log(getExt(string2));
console.log(getExt(string3));
```

Comment: Actually, I needed the file extenions and not the file names. And, null, empty string or undefined for that which don't have an extension.

Answer (score 4):

You can split from the last slash, and then split on the dot  in the item after the last slash.
If that length is 0 then you know it doesn't have an extention

Comment: What if we got such file names as `http://www.example.com/uploads/yyy.xyz.def.po.png`. Actually, we can't go hard on length for the dots.

Comment: Why don't you split from the last slash and then split from the dot, if that fails you know it won't have a extention.

Comment: I've edited the answer, if that helped you, i would appriciate it if you maked it as the solution :)